# Getting "NameError: undefined local variable or method" from Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run this simple program:

```
puts " Hello, what's you're name?"
name  = gets.chomp
puts 'Hello,'+ '' + name+ '.'

if name =='Chris'
  puts 'What a lovely name!'
end
```

But I keep getting this output error:

```
1.9.3-p392 :003 > ruby exerise72.rb
NameError: undefined local variable or method `exerise72' for main:Object
    from (irb):3
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to issue a command for your shell inside the Rails console. Type `quit` then press <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit it and return to your normal shell prompt.

Then you can try:

```
ruby exerise72.rb
```

It is *really* important to know the difference between your OS shell and IRB/Rails' console, and any other shells or command-line interfaces you end up in. They're very powerful, and not knowing what you are doing, or where you are doing it, is a good way to randomly clutter up your disk, lose files and accidentally delete things.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the `ruby` command outside the ruby console. The ruby console (irb) it's for executing inline commands. If you want to execute a complete script (your `exerise72.rb` program), you have to execute in cmd, bash or similar.

Comment: Thanks guys!! It's important for me to understand the fundamentals of ruby in order to succeed in it!